# prefers-color-scheme reads it on OS-level instead of browser

Tags: javascript, css

I specifically target **Chrome** and would like to keep the solution in pure **CSS** if possible, but if the only way to accomplish this is by using **JS**, I'm open to that solution too.

`prefers-color-scheme` in CSS reads the mode on OS level. If I'll set **Dark** mode in Windows and **Light** mode in Chrome, `prefers-color-scheme: dark` will be still set. I need `prefers-color-scheme` (or an alternative) to respect the browser theme instead of OS.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "Set light mode in Chrome" mean in particular?

Comment: Is this for all users, or just for your own browser?

Comment: @DavidThomas for all users of the browser extension

Comment: @AKX at chrome://settings/appearance there is "mode" option

Comment: @yegorchik There isn't one there on my Chrome 121.0.6167.160.

Comment: @AKX same Chrome version, it's there. Odd